# What parameter do I pass into NSUserDefaults.synchronize()?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm trying to save a high score in my spritekit game. Based on all the tutorials I've watched and the stack overflow answers i've read, the following code should work:

```
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(highScore, forKey: "highScore")
 NSUserDefaults.synchronize()
```

however I keep encountering an error with the

```
NSUserDefaults.synchronize()
```

portion.The error states "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call"  All the places i've looked seem to use that code with no error. I'm aware that there is going to be/ was recently an update to swift. Did this update cause something to change with the synchronize function, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `synchronize` on `standardUserDefaults`.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
```

Keep in mind that there is no need to call `synchronize`.

Answer (score 3):

`synchronize` is an **instance method**, so you should call it on an instance, not the class:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

However, you shouldn't need to do this.

In the [CoreFoundation release notes for OS X 10.8](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreFoundationOlderNotes/), it was stated:

> CFPreferences Synchronization
> `CFPreferencesSynchronize()` (and therefore `CFPreferencesAppSynchronize()` and `-[NSUserDefaults synchronize]`) is now automatic in virtually all cases. The only remaining reason to call it is if you need a separate process to be able to synchronously access the values you just set; for example if you set a preference, then post a notification which another process receives and reads the same preference. Most regular applications will never need to do this, and applications that do are encouraged to use an inter-process communication API (for example XPC) to communicate with the other process rather than using the preferences system for IPC.
>
> `CFPreferencesSynchronize()` is also much faster in 10.8, and will avoid doing any work if there are no outstanding changes to read or write.

And the [Foundation release notes for 10.9](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/):

> **-[NSUserDefaults synchronize] is not generally useful**
>
> You should only need to call `-synchronize` if a separate application will be reading the default that you just set, or if a process that does not use AppKit is terminating. In most applications neither of these should ever occur, and `-synchronize` should not be called. Note that prior to Mac OS X 10.8.4 there was a bug that caused AppKit to automatically synchronize slightly prematurely during application termination, so preferences set in response to windows closing while the application is terminating might not be saved; this has been fixed.